# Convert Date rows to column using redshfit

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, pivot-table

I have a SQL table that contains date, category, revenue, revenue2 and revenue3. Looks like the below table :

| EMPID | Date | Revenue1 | Revenue2 | Revenue 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 2015-08-01 | 1000 | 1000 | 2000 |
| USA | 2015-09-01 | 2000 | 1000 | 1000 |
| USA | 2015-09-01 | 2000 | 1000 | 1000 |
| USA | 2015-07-01 | 3000 | 1000 | 1000 |
| CHINA | 2015-07-01 | 4000 | 1000 | 3000 |
| INDIA | 2015-07-01 | 5000 | 1000 | 1000 |
| INDIA | 2015-08-01 | 5000 | 1000 | 2000 |
| CHINA | 2015-09-01 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 |

I want the below results :

| EMPID | CATEGORY | 2015-09-01 | 2015-08-01 | 2015-07-01 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | REVENUE1 | 4000 | 1000 | 3000 |
| USA | REVENUE2 | 2000 | 1000 | 1000 |
| USA | REVENUE3 | 2000 | 2000 | 1000 |
| INDIA | REVENUE1 | ... | ... | ... |
| INDIA | REVENUE2 | ... | ... | ... |
| INDIA | REVENUE3 | ... | ... | ... |
| CHINA | REVENUE1 | ... | ... | ... |

the date mentioned is the first day of the month.

also I dont mind hardcoding the dates. Can someone help me with the solution. I dont have any code for now.

I was in an assumption that pivot function cannot be used in redshift since my previous code hadnt worked. below is the code I tried to unpivot first and used cte, later within the cte i tried to pivot which is not working. can anyone please see the code and suggest if something is missing.

```
select cte as (select * from (select empid, revenue1, revenue2,revenue3, date from table)  UNPIVOT (totalrevenue for Revenues IN (revenue1, revenue2, revenue3)))
```

`select * from (select  empid, totalrevenue, revenues , date  from cte) PIVOT (sum(totalrevenue) FOR date in ('2022-06-01', '2022-07-01)'))`

Comment: Hi @Anushika, why you can't use PIVOT ?, dates are always the first day of every months ?

Comment: @pfigueredo, datagrip is not supporting pivot.

Comment: @Anushika: DataGrip doesn't support anything in SQL - it's the database server you _connect_ to that does this.

Comment: I have connected to redshift. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: I am currently connected to redshift and the code is not working since it does not recognize cross join lateral @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @Anushika: well you tagged your question with PostgreSQL which is something different than Amazon Redshift - my answer was for Postgres, not for Redshift

Comment: sorry for the confusion @a_horse_with_no_name